# prime faces ajax not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

We have a JSF project with the following versions of JARs:

1. Prime Faces 5.1
2. JSF 2.0
3. Javaee-api 5
4. But the Project Facets(in eclipse) defines JSF 2.2, we never changed it.
5. JPA 2 ( javaee-api 5)
6. Ejb 3.0

Our ajax is not working.

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="enrolledInPlanFlag" value="#{phInfoBean.enrldPlanFlag}"  label="Action" >
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes" />
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="No" />
 <p:ajax  process="enrolledInPlanFlag" update="@form"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>

<p:dialog id="dialog" header="APTC Warning" widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true" height="200" width="500" resizable="false" rendered="#{phInfoBean.enrldPlanFlag eq 'Yes'}">
```

I am trying to display dialog based on the selectOneRadio. But the AJAX is not working and we have the wierd situation where sometimes it works and sometimes it not.

We have annotated managed bean with @ViewScoped.

Please help.

Comment: Define 'not working' from a developer point of view. AJAX comprises several thing. Sending a request, processing it, getting a response etc. Investigate more yourself and show minimal beancode to

Comment: We are trying to define <p:ajax> for a radio button. My requirement is that on selection of any of the option I should display the dialog. But when I click on the radio button, the page doest repond. I cannot see the dialog box. I tried with the panelGrid and other input components from JSF but not luck. Please help

Comment: From a **developer** point of view please. This is again from a user perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make it work

You never show your dialog in your code. You could attach an `oncomplete` event to your `p:ajax`

```
 <p:ajax process="enrolledInPlanFlag" update="@form" oncomplete="PF('dlg1') != null ? PF('dlg1').show() : ''" />
```

The condition `PF('dlg1') != null` is required as if you choose "No" your dialog is no longer rendered in your page, therefore PF('widgetVarOfDialog') is unreachable.

- Additional notes

I would improve this code by:

1. Changing `enrldPlanFlag` to a boolean instead of a string (cleaner IMO)
2. Display the dialog programatically in an listener (called from your p:ajax) if the boolean is true

Why? To leave the logic in your bean instead of your .xhtml page